# YouTube Data API V3 - Error Access Not Configured

Tags: youtube-api

I have a problem with the use of new YouTube Data API V3.

I'm still using version V2 but I plan to migrate my web application to the new version. After doing some tests with a call using the web browser type:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=TYkPtAmJn4E&key=***********************&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

I get the following error:

```
  {
   "error": {
    "errors": [
     {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
      "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
     }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  }
```

I state that the console should be configured correctly, as you can see from the attached images, since it works fine for more than a year with the V2 version of the API.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks.!

Comment: Problem solved: in Developers Console - Public API access to set Referers "Any referer allowed" and then regenerate the key! ... Thanks!

Comment: whats that means pls help

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a project, enable [Data API v3 from console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) and use the credentials you create for that project.

Comment: Yes, I have already created all of this and is working perfectly with YouTube API V2 for over a year. I tried to post here pictures of my setup but I have not the requirements in this forum to post pictures! Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just go through from scratch https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: Already done everything but nothing changes !! I even regenerated the apikey but still nothing !! Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved: in Developers Console - Public API access to set Referers "Any referer allowed" and then regenerate the key! ... Thanks!

Comment: hi @Maurizio Schirinzi EMI can you pls clearly explain about how to resolve this issue, bcz i have still facing this issue

Comment: Almost 2019 no, still doesn't work anything. Disabled, enabled, regenerated, added referers before key generation, regenerated key after it, whatever. It's just not working. Unbelievable...

Comment: I ran into this issue and found that creating a completely new project fixed the issue. No disabling, enabling, or deleting keys made a difference, but a new project did.